# How do I escape '+' in data I’m sending via AJAX in Mootools?

Tags: php, javascript, mootools

I was building a simple web based calculator which takes equations from a HTML form, evaluates it on the server using PHP and sends the result back.

I am using Mootools to send the data via the `req.send` AJAX operation.

But, each time I have a '+' in an equation, it is not seen on the POST data the server gets.

Any ideas why this is happening and how I can work around it?

eg:

`10 + 12` in HTML form is seen as `10 12` in the `$_POST` data.

The Mootools send command I am using is something like this with

```
<textarea name="equationTextArea">10+12</textarea>

req.send("eqn="+$('equationTextArea').value);
```

Upon submit, I see `$_REQUEST['eqn']` as `10 12`.

Comment: Thanks Paul for making the question sound better! I am new here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the function `encodeURIComponent` over your text value. It, well.. uri encodes your text.

Comment: I have seen other websites take equations in POST without any uri encoding

Comment: We do this for certain characters, like + which is a "space" according to RFC 1738. If other websites don't appear to throw uri encoding over their values, it's likely a framework solves this problem for them. In this/your case it does not seem to happen like that.

Comment: It's not just `+`. If you forget to URL-encode components of your submission, any `&`, `%nn` or non-ASCII sequences inside that content are going to cause trouble. You are creating an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` dataset of the form `a=b&c=d`, regardless of whether that's used as a `GET` query string or a `POST` request body. @arbithero: Yes, lots of sites put a dataset together without encoding. That's because most webdevs haven't a bleeding clue. Those scripts *will* break as soon as you put unexpected characters in.

Comment: I know, I said "like +", meant as 'for example' ;) But good to point it out for people who are unfamiliar with it!

Comment: Your welcome! (can you mark this answer as solved/answered? for future visitors of the question)

Answer (score 1):

Set your form's encoding to `multipart/form-data` - this is an alternative to the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and doesn't encode a space  into a plus sign `+`.

Example [from the w3.org reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2):

```
<form action="http://example.com/cgi/handle"
   enctype="multipart/form-data"
   method="post">
```

Comment: This is doing an XMLHttpRequest. If you wanted to send `multipart/form-data` you'd have to create that request body manually, which is more effort than for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 0):

Your text most likely either need to be [URLEncoded](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

Comment: Don't let the php tag fool you, the problem in this question is client-side. Despite that, in PHP I personally prefer `rawurlencoding` as it is RFC 1738 compliant.